# Running STK scenario with Python integration

Tags: python, stk-agi

I have created a scenario in STK 12.4 with a couple of satellites that will pass over a target location. I want to have a function that is called while the scenario is running.

Does the Python API have functions for playing out the scenario from start to end time?
Something like this:

```
while scenario.running:
      if satellite.conditional == true:
         doSomething()
```